# Como hacer un movimiento en miniwin? C++

Tags: array, c++11

Ando desarrollando un programa de `miniwin` en **dev c++**, que genera un carro en el medio de la pantalla y aleatoriamente genera edificios detrás de el. Pero mi objetivo es hacer que al presionar el espacio, los edificios se muevan de derecha a izquierda creando la ilusión de que el carro se esta moviendo.

Hasta ahora he podido generar los edificios pero no lo logro hacer que se muevan y que se generen nuevos edificios a la par para dar la ilusión de movimiento. Si alguien se le ocurre una idea por favor me serviría muchísimo.

Este es mi código de momento:

```
    #include "miniwin.h"
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <iostream>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace miniwin;
    using namespace std;          
    to_string()

    float posx = 0;

    void edificios(int x, int y){
        int numeros[30] = {};
        srand(time(NULL));

        for(int x = 0; x < 30; x++){
            numeros[x] = rand() % (300 - 150 + 1) + 150;
        }       

        color(ROJO);
        for(int x = x * 20; x < 30; x++){
            rectangulo_lleno(x*20,numeros[x],x*20+20,400);
        }
    }

    int main(){

        float x, y;
        vredimensiona(600, 600);      
        color(CYAN);
        rectangulo_lleno(0, 0, 600, 600);    
        color(AMARILLO);
        rectangulo_lleno(0, 400, 600, 600);    
        edificios(x, y);    
        refresca();

        while(1)  
        {
            switch(tecla())  // a partir de acá supongo que esta mal porque no logro hacer que funcione
            {
                case ESPACIO:            
                if(y = 0){              
                    posx -= 20;              
                    borra();
                    edificios(0, 0);    
                }
            }
            refresca;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu programa está mal desde el principio:

**Llamas a la función sin inicializar las variables**

```
int main()
{
  float x,y; // x e y tienen valores aleatorios (basura)

  edificios(x,y); // le pasas basura a la función
}
```

Esto puede provocar comportamientos erráticos al usar valores que no sabes qué contienen.

**Los tipos de la función son diferentes de los declarados inicialmente**

```
void edificios(int x,int y); // x e y son de tipo int

float x,y;                   // x e y son de tipo float
```

Esto puede provocar pérdidas de precisión y comportamientos anómalos

**La función `edificios` no debería recibir `x` e `y`**

Son valores que no necesita, ya que inicializa su propio rango de valores:

```
void edificios(int x,int y) // Recibe x e y
{
    for(int x=0;x<30;x++) // Inicializa x
    { ... }      

    // No usa y para nada
}
```

**Función rand extraña**

```
rand()%(300-150+1)+150;
```

Lo que hace ese código es:

1. Genera un número entero aleatorio
2. Calcula el módulo `rand%(300-150+1) = rand%151`, lo que genera un número en el rango [0, 150]
3. Al resultado le suma 150

El paso dos podría simplificarse directamente a `rand%151`, para no crear confusiones innecesarias. Aunque por otro lado, desde C++11 ya existe una librería específica para números aleatorios mucho más potente y flexible que `rand`:

```
#include <random>

// Para generar la semilla
static std::random_device dev;

// Generador de números aleatorios
static std::mt19937 rng(dev());

// Distribuye los números aleatorios de forma uniforme sobre el rango [150, 300]
static std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(150,300);

for(int x=0;x<30;x++)
{
  numeros[x]= dist(rng);
}
```

**Desplazar edificios**

Tu programa **no guarda** la posición ni el tamaño de los edificios. Si bien es cierto que tienes por ahí el array `numeros`, ese array tiene dos problemas:

1. Al no ser una variable estática, sus valores se pierden cuando la ejecución abandona la función.
2. En cada iteración reescribes los valores del array

Estos dos problemas imposibilitan que puedas guardar el estado de los edificios entre refrescos de pantalla.

Necesitas gestionar un array cuyo ámbito (vida del array) sea superior al de la función. Esto te permitirá usar el mismo array varias veces (preservando sus valores).

```
#include <vector>

void pintar_edificios(std::vector<int> const& edificios)
{
  for( size_t x = 0; x < edificios.size(); ++x )
  {
    color(ROJO);
    rectangulo_lleno(x*20, edificios[x], x*20+20, 400);
  }
}

void generar_edificios(std::vector<int> const& edificios)
{
  static std::random_device dev;
  static std::mt19937 rng(dev());
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(150,300);

  while( edificios.size() < 30 )
  {
    edificios.push_back(dist(rng));
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> edificios;

  while(true)
  {
    // Rellena el array de edificios
    genera_edificios(edificios);

    // pinta los edificios
    pintar_edificios(edificios);

    // Elimina el primer edificio
    edificios.erase(edificios.begin());
  }
}
```

Como la posición `x` de los edificios viene dada por su posición dentro del array, al eliminar el primer edificio los demás se desplazarán automáticamente. El hueco que deja el primer edificio será ocupado por un nuevo edificio que *entrará* por la derecha.

Este diseño te permite, además, darle propiedades a los edificios, como por ejemplo color, para que no sean todos rojos:

```
class Edificio
{
public:
  Edificio(int color, int altura)
    : color_(color)
    , altura_(altura)
  { }

  int GetColor()
  { return color_; }

  int GetAltura()
  { return algura_; }

private:
  int color_;
  int altura_;
};

void pintar_edificios(std::vector<Edificio> const& edificios)
{
  for( size_t x = 0; x < edificios.size(); ++x )
  {
    color(edificios[x].GetColor());
    rectangulo_lleno(x*20, edificios[x].GetAltura(), x*20+20, 400);
  }
}

void generar_edificios(std::vector<Edificio> const& edificios)
{
  static std::random_device dev;
  static std::mt19937 rng(dev());
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> gen_alturas(150,300);
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> gen_colores(0,MAX_COLOR); // MAX_COLOR = ??

  while( edificios.size() < 30 )
  {
    edificios.emplace_back(gen_colores(rng), gen_alturas(rng));
  }
}
```